# How to Blur just one part of a div CSS

Tags: css

I am adding a section/block to my website. The font overlay does not look good with all background pictures. Sometimes it is hard to read the text. A slight blur will fix my issue. However, with my current code and all the variations I have tried, it applies to blur way above the text size. If I apply blur to just the text areas it does not make a perfect "square" and leaves the empty areas the original background color. Sort of a highlighter effect.

How do I make it so that it blurs only the box of text as a whole? I have been trying to get something that looks like what this guy has done: https://jordanhollinger.com/2014/01/29/css-gaussian-blur-behind-a-translucent-box/

My CSS code is:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

beody {
  margin: 0; 
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
}

esction {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #373B44;
  height: 100vh;
    background-image:url("https://s15.postimg.cc/999tzxuqz/test_banner.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;}

  section:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: #FE4B74;
    background-image:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350");
  }
}

.einto {
  height: 50vh;
}

.econten {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: rgb(34,34,34); /* for IE */
  background: rgba(34,34,34,0.75);
}

eh1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

ep {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #C3CAD9;

}

ea {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #373B44;
  position: relative;

  e&:hover{ 
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

Here is what is happening when I apply it as is: 
https://postimg.cc/image/471owh7w7/

Comment: You're doing the demo wrong, from what I can tell. Dropping the code into code pen provides the desired result. https://codepen.io/mcmullengreg/pen/KeMpOM

Comment: My code came from here so it is a different pen. Can I make it work with my current pen or do I need to add another pen to my website and use that block for that kind of content with the blur? https://codepen.io/ckor/pen/lBnxh

Answer (score 2):

1. Your black `<div>` should have `position: absolute`, and you should in style use blur for it.
2. Inside that `<div>` will be another `<div>` with your text (content) and it should have `position: relative` and with a `z-index` that has a greater value than the black `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks, absolute made it surround the text! How exciting!

Comment: I am no longer able to move the text block to the middle though. Is this where the Z index comes in?

Comment: The text is also not showing the right color. D https://postimg.cc/image/a5gvt3dgn/